# SQL Substring function usage

Tags: sql, substring, trim, instr

This the column Description

```
Entity=10||WorkdayReferenceID=9000100332||HCMCostCenterMgr=nicoleb@broadinstitute.org||FRP=||
```

I want to retrieve the emailid only in the above scenario the desired output would be

```
nicoleb@broadinstitute.org
```

I tried using this:

```
select RTRIM(NVL(SUBSTR(TL.DESCRIPTION,(INSTR(TL.DESCRIPTION, '=',1,3)+1),
(LENGTH(TL.DESCRIPTION)-1)),'TL.DESCRIPTION'), '|') AS CCM
```

But after that new value of FRP was added so it got wrong .

Comment: For this kind of advanced string manipulation you would probably need non-standard SQL functions. What database system are you using?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Most of the functions used above are product specific.

Comment: Add more sample data, with variation. And also update the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (and it is a big assumption) that there is only ever one `@` in the data, the approach would be find the `@`, and then you want the text that is after the preceding `=` and before the next `|`. I do not know if the email address is always after `HCMCostCenterMgr=` so I won't assume that (but if that is the case the solution is easier).

It looks like you might be using Oracle (I see a `NVL` function), but I did this as SQL Server (it is more familiar off the top of my head). Here is a small script that will return just the email address you want - you can easily change these functions to Oracle if you need a version for Oracle.

```sql
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(200);
SELECT @data = 'Entity=10||WorkdayReferenceID=9000100332||HCMCostCenterMgr=nicoleb@broadinstitute.org||FRP=||';

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@data, 1, CHARINDEX('|', @data, CHARINDEX('@', @data)) - 1)), 1, CHARINDEX('=', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@data, 1, CHARINDEX('|', @data, CHARINDEX('@', @data)) - 1)))-1));
```

It is ugly, but SQL often gets a bit convoluted. I had to reverse the string to find things before the '@' and then reverse it at the end to get the value in the correct direction.